# What's a non-redundant way to Group by & Order by same set of columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, presto

I have a query

```
select A, B, C, AVG(D)
from table
group by A,B
order by A,B
```

I feel group by, order by for the same 2 columns in same 2 order is a bit redundant.

Is there a cleaner way to do that?

Comment: Your method is correct.

Comment: If `A`, `B` or `C` are complex expressions you can use their indexes (start from 1) like `group by 1,2 order by 1,2`

Comment: If you group by doesn't sure order by to. You can order a lot of combination (order by column order, DESC/ASC ).

Comment: This query can only work in PostgreSQL if column `C` has a functional dependency on (`A`, `B`). Otherwise you'll need to aggregate it. And, to respond to your question, the query is clean; your `ORDER BY` may correspond to the `GROUP BY` or not; that's up to your requirements.